# Translating jquery codes into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote code with jquery. but I want to convert it to plain javascript codes. can you help me?

```js
$(function() {
    var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
        this.el = el || {};
        this.multiple = multiple || false;

        
        var links = this.el.find('.rewrite');
        
        links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
    }

    Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
        var $el = e.data.el;
            $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();

        $next.slideToggle();
        $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

        if (!e.data.multiple) {
            $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
        };
    }   

    var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});


  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

https://github.com/dvlt39/cookie/blob/master/script.js

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code porting service, please show an attempt first.

Comment: I shared the codes I wrote on github.com

Comment: If you had written all this code yourself I would expect you to be able to have tried something at least please show us.

Answer (score -1):

Since your code contains reference to other jQuery functions, porting is a bit cumbersome. Note the usage of `slideToggle` and `slideUp`.

If you want an easy way to figure out how to port code from jQuery to vanilla JS, you can check out: [**You might not need jQuery**](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Here is an equivalent ES5/6 class (sans slide logic):

```js
class Accordion {
  constructor(el, multiple = false) {
    this.el.querySelectorAll('.rewrite').forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.dropdown();
      })
    });
  }

  dropdown() {
    const next = this.el.nextElementSibling;

    this.el.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');

    if (!this.multiple) {
      this.el.querySelectorAll('.submenu').forEach(menu => {
        if (menu !== next) {
          menu.parentElement.classList.remove('open')
        }
      });
    };
  }
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  const accordion = new Accordion(document.querySelector('#accordion'), false);
});
```

Comment: Can you review the codes on this link and help?

Comment: If you need a code review, you will need to post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).